# Excel, VBA find date in column

Tags: vba, excel

I have calendar in excel like this:
[image]

What i'm trying to do. I want to write a macro that after mark cell and press button, Macro get string (here: user1), then back 1 column to get time and go up to get date (in this case 3). BUT
I've already got user1 and date, but I can not get the date

Here's a code

```
Dim cell As Object
Dim client As String
Dim date As Date
Dim hour As Date
Dim rowc As Long
Dim colc As Long
    For Each cell In Selection
       client = cell.Value
       colc = ActiveCell.Column
       rowc = ActiveCell.Row
    Next cell

    hour = Cells(rowc, colc - 1).Value
Cells(4, 17).Value = hour 'works to this point

    t = rowc
    colc = colc-1 
    For i = t To 0

    If IsDate(Cells(i, colc).Value) = True Then

     date= Cells(i, colc).Value

    Else
    rowc = rowc - 1
    End If
    Next i



 'Cells(3, 17).Value = date
 Cells(5, 17).Value = client
```

Explanation of line : colc = colc-1 - Every date (31, 1, 2...) it is a 2 cells merged together. If user1 cell address is f.e. 8,14 so 3-11-2016 cell column is not 8 but 7.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

It seems that this loop does not even loops. When i change true for false, msgbox did not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `For` loop does not work that way. If t = 10, and you have `For i = t To 0`, loop will not iterate even once, because 10 > 0. As far as I have understood your request, you want to make `i` to go bacward. Try the same with `Do While` loop:

```
i = t
Do while i > 0
    If IsDate(Cells(i, colc).Value) = True Then
        date= Cells(i, colc).Value
    Else
        rowc = rowc - 1
    End If
    i = i - 1
Loop
```

Comment: Damn... my rookie mistake. Works as charm. Thanks1